# Spring Authorization Server: Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I have a basic Spring Authorization Server set up as a Spring Boot application. I am attempting to access this server via an angular application using angular-auth-oidc-client.

When I attempt to log in, I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/mydomain/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've made multiple attempts to fix this issue, but have been unsuccessful.

Relevant parts of the Configuration for the authorization server are below:

```java
    // @formatter:off
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        
        // removed

    }
    // @formatter:on

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);

        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return source;
    }   

    // @formatter:off
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
        
        return http.build();
    }
    // @formatter:on
```

That CORS Configuration seems to be wide open, but I'm still seeing the issue.

Am I just making a stupid mistake that I'm not seeing?

Edit: yes, I've configured that port and domain in application.yml:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9000
  servlet:
    context-path: /mydomain
```

Comment: Make sure you have the correct import (there are two `CorsConfigurationSource`): `import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;`. See [this commit](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/commit/2000fabdc518912dbead71d2a4e35df90c283f87) for what I added to get it working. (Note: This is an older branch)

Comment: Also see [related webinar](https://tanzu.vmware.com/content/webinars/mar-10-getting-started-with-spring-authorization-server) where we demo the above branch.

Comment: No, I'm definitely using the one you mentioned, not the reactive one.

Comment: I copied your CorsConfiguration and setup, and now I'm in a redirect loop. I guess that's progress, but the direction of that progress is up in the air.

Comment: Have you added `.cors()` to both filter chains?